VACUUM and ANALYZE required after restore?
Is there a need to either VACUUM or ANALYZE, or both, the tables after running the OUTPUT of pg_dumpall in PostgreSQL 16?

pg_dumpall > all_database.sql
Freshly install PostgreSQL 16.4
psql < all_database.sql

After the above steps, is there a need to run VACUUM and / or ANALYZE on the tables (specially the large ones)?
My personal opinion is that VACUUM is not needed because the entire data has been recently created, but I want an experience hand to second it. Regarding, ANALYZE, I cannot say.

Since the data is being loaded through a normal backend process via psql (as opposed to say pg_upgrade, which bypasses that), autovac will kick in and do its thing.  Whether this will happen fast enough to suit your purposes, I cannot say.
Running the VACUUM ANALYZE manually will get it done faster, as by default it is not throttled the way autovac is.  Also, if you do it manually then you know when it is done (when you get returned to the command prompt) as opposed to autovac where you need to specifically investigate its progress.

My personal opinion is that VACUUM is not needed because the entire data has been recently created

Besides cleaning dead tuples, VACUUM also serves to set the hint-bits and visibility map, which can be important on recently created data.
